# What is the purpose of <Node "node"> in write_graphite plugin of collectd?

Tags: graphite, collectd

I am trying to understand what the purpose of the "Node" tag is. This is the plugin from my config file. What is the situation where one needs to use multiple Node tags?

```
<Plugin write_graphite>
  <Node "default">
    Host "graphitehost"
    Port "2003"
    Protocol "tcp"
    LogSendErrors true
    Prefix "collectd."
    StoreRates true
    AlwaysAppendDS false
    EscapeCharacter "_"
  </Node>
</Plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply when you want to send the data to multiple graphite servers.

Comment: Yes, in this case. But also if you want *any data stream* to go to multiple destinations. Or to the same one too with maybe different namespaces.